# What is going to happen to HHA?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

What is going to happen to HHA?
Will restarting my town cause the houses in HHA to disappear? I thought they might stay because these gamers are connected to your streetpass right? Or will that be wiped out too? It would be nice if I could get my furniture back once I deleted my save file. (after I unlock the HHA of course.) 
Sorry for the bad English!

Answer (score 3):

The houses in the HHA disappear if you restart your game (I'm pretty sure that's the question you have, but... eh?) The houses aren't connected to Streetpass per se. You get their data via Streetpass and update it via Streetpass, but you would have to re-pass those people to see their houses again.

So the data from their houses gets wiped out with your reset. Streetpass itself is a 3DS concept, not an Animal Crossing one. So those people still be in your Mii Parade area, but their Animal Crossing data will be gone from the game.

You also can't get your furniture back through HHA, because you won't have your old save data (also, you can't buy your own stuff from the HHA, you'd have to buy it from the catalog in the general store because your house isn't in your HHA. If someone in your HHA has the same objects you do, you could buy it in the HHA... but you shouldn't because those items are priced with a 20% bell increase or something like that). Therefore, you can't use the HHA to get your old furniture back. You could trade your furniture to a friend and then trade it back after you've made a new file? But you can't get your stuff from the HHA.